# 301 Redirect Issue in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

All of my redirects that have the following pattern aren't working as expected:

```
Redirect 301 /folderA/folderB/ http://externalwebsite.com/folderC
```

Instead of redirecting to http://externalwebsite.com/folderC, the redirect goes to:

```
http://externalwebsite.com/folderCfolderB
```

As you can see, the "folderB" is being appended to the destination URL.

Is there a server/apache setting that could be causing this? Or could it be something else in my .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect directive appends rest of the old uri from pattern to its destination path. To avoid this you need to use `RedirectMatch`

```
RedirectMatch 301 /folderA/folderB/ http://example.com/folderC
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked great. Crazy that I've never come across "RedirectMatch". Live and learn.